# How do I set the default value of a parameter to an empty array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Regarding the following code I have two questions:

1. When I compile it I get the warning/error "Cannot convert 'any[]' to 'Array'". Is that because `public songPaths: Array = []` isn't legit and I should just go with `public songPaths: any = []` ?
2. Is `Object` an appropriate default value for `public song:Object = new Audio()`?

Example:

```
'use strict';

class Boombox{
      constructor(public track: number, public codec: string, public song:Object = new Audio(), public currentTime: number = 0, public playing:bool = false, public titles: any = [], public songPaths: Array = []){
      }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To declare an untyped array, use `any[]` rather than `Array`:

```
public songPaths: any[] = []
```

You should specify the type if possible, for example:

```
public songPaths: string[] = []
```

---

You are not using `Object` as a default value. `Object` is the type and `new Audio()` is the default value. If possible the type should be the actual type that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. `string[] = []` was just was I was looking for.

And yes you're right I was incorrect in calling `Object` my default value when it was in fact the type.

Switching `Object` to `Audio` gives me the warning/error 'The name 'Audio' does not exist in the current scope'

I'll need to figure out what the type of `new Audio()` is or go with `Object`

Thanks again!

Comment: @cgcardona: Every object return the type `object`, even the built in ones. I get the same error when I try to use `Audio` as type. Using `Object` as type would be a resonable compromise if you can't figure out how to use `Audio`. An alternative would be to encapsulate the `Audio` object in a class, then you could use that as type.

Answer (score 2):

If 'Audio' is actually a type you want to use members of, then don't declare it to be type 'Object', as you will only have the members of Object available to you.  Either declare it to be type 'any', or better yet, add an interface declaration for the members you want to use to get type checking.  For example:

```
interface Audio { 
    listen: () => void;
};

function foo(x: Object, y: any, z: Audio) {
    x.listen(); // <-- Error: "The property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Object'"
    y.listen(); // <-- OK
    z.lisen();  // <-- Detects typo due to interface declaration and gives error "The property 'lisen' does not exist on type 'Audio'"
    z.listen(); // <-- Works fine (and gives you intellisense based on declaration).
}
```